# Table Pagination

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, tables, pagination, ease-of-use

I have a standard table with around 1500 enteries as shown below : [image]

How do I capture the fact that I want to migrate on a particular page(for eg say page no.13) without having to click multiple times to achieve the result?
Any other pagination ideas would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to add an input field for that and it's actually commonly used in websites with large numbers of pages.

[image]

Here is another example where the input is hidden by a button:

[image]

And the last example:

[image]

Comment: Something that I would like to understand is that how beneficial is this option altogether and does it really make sense to keep this feature?How much complexity can it introduce on my backend wrt load/search time?

Comment: If you have lots of pages, a feature like this is a must, because the alternative way to click 300 times on "next" to get to page 300 sounds pretty bad. About the complexity of the backend: there is no complexity because the event for the next/prev page calls the same function as this. Instead of passing to the server the number of the next page you will pass the number of the page in the input field. In my opinion this is a perfect solution for your question :)

Comment: Are you sure that different users prefers a different number of items per page? Why is it important to give the user the option to choose number per page?

Answer (score 0):

Complementing dimshik's answer, I would also suggest giving the user a search functionality. It is much easier to search and filter a keyword rather than trying to remember and browse to its page (which is often a futile task).

Comment: Yes, I have a search feature in place for the table at the top,I just cropped the pagination to ask my question...thanks for the suggestion.